# Can I destructure an event handler object? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object, called value from Firebase Realtime db in my component. With an onClick button, I want to push the values of the object plus an extra ID (tuid) back to the database. How can I fix it so that I can send 'suid' and 'content' back to the db?

```
  function sendMessage(event) {
    // console.log("sendMessage -> event", event.target.value); // <--- is an object
    setWriteError(null);
    try {
      db.ref("messages/toDisplay").push({
        suid: event.target.value.uid,         //<---- .uid fails
        content: event.target.value.content,  //<---- .content fails
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        tuid: user.email, // use email as user uid
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setWriteError(error.message);
    }
  }
```

with this code:

```
    return (
    <section className="conversation">
      {readError ? readError : ""}
      <Header user={user} />

      {dashboard.map((value, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <span error={writeError}>{value.content}</span>{" "}
          <button))}
            onClick={sendMessage}
            value={value}>     {/* {value.content} with event.target.value works */}
            Accepted
          </button> 
          ... </div> ))} </section>
```

where tuid is the currently logged in user; suid is the user IN the object received from FB db.

This is what works

```
  function sendMessage(event) {
    setWriteError(null);
    try {
      db.ref("messages/toDisplay").push({
        //suid: event.target.value.uid,  <--- problem commented out
        content: event.target.value,   // so no problem
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        tuid: user.email, 
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setWriteError(error.message);
    }
  }
```

with this button

```
    <section className="conversation">
      {readError ? readError : ""}
      <Header user={user} />

      {dashboard.map((value, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <span error={writeError}>{value.content}</span>{" "}
          <button))}
            onClick={sendMessage}
            value={value.content}>   {/*no problem here*/}
            Accepted
          </button> 
          ... </div> ))} </section>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your title relates to your post?

Comment: I also don't know what this question means: "How can I fix it so that I can send suid and content back to the db?"

Comment: Oops! I tried to be as clear as I could given my limited coding experience;  however, thankfully @DrewReece got what I meant so I was able to try his solutions.

Answer (score 2):

React uses [Synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) that are (usually very quickly) nullified and returned back to the event pool. As such, when you enqueue these event properties into a structure that is likely later processed, those values have been nullified by then.

[Event Pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent`
> object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
> event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
> such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

You can either save a local copy of the event properties you need, or try to persist the event object.

## Solution 1 - Destructure the Event Properties (Recommended)

```
function sendMessage(event) {
  const { value: { content, uid: suid } } = event.target;
  
  setWriteError(null);
  try {
    db.ref("messages/toDisplay").push({
      suid,
      content,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      tuid: user.email,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    setWriteError(error.message);
  }
}
```

## Solution 2 - Persist the event object

> Note:
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
> should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
> synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
> retained by user code.

```
function sendMessage(event) {
  event.persist();
  
  setWriteError(null);
  try {
    db.ref("messages/toDisplay").push({
      suid: event.target.value.uid,
      content: event.target.value.content,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      tuid: user.email,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    setWriteError(error.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @drew! I tried both and sadly they did not work. I wanted the destructuring to work.

Comment: @AngelD Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Can you validate the destructured values from the event object exist? I see no reason for the destructuring to fail other than if you are running an older transpiler. Are there any errors?

Comment: I got this output in the console      "__reactEventHandlers$...": Object { error: "Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.toDisplay.suid'", children: "test message" }  "

Comment: When move suid to last place in the order of things, I got `previousElementSibling: span​​
"__reactEventHandlers$.....": {…}
​​​
children: "test message "
​​​
error: "Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'messages.toDisplay.content'"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }`

Comment: What is `db.ref("messages/toDisplay")` in the `sendMessage` handler?

Comment: I appreciate the help that you've given me @drew. It might be a Firebase Realtime database quirk and that's it. I might have to go with the basic version that works. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It adds the attributes of the message on a new node in Firebase. ie. root > messages > toDisplay. Under normal circumstances, I would get a new node with message UID, and under that appears content, timestamp and the uid of the current user (that I've called tuid).